# Is there an extension to sort Graphql query definition for vscode?

Tags: graphql, vscode-extensions

I have a query like this:

```
node {
  id
  age
  name
  job
  pet {
    id
    name
    age
  }
}
```

Is there a vscode extension that allows me to sort it? Like this:

```
node {
  age
  id
  job
  name
  pet {
    age
    id
    name
  }
}
```